# How to create div, content of which will always be crossed out diagonally?

Tags: css

So I have a div, content of which should always be crossed out diagonally.

I've tried few solutions with few elements that had absolute positions but it wasn't good enough, because content and size of the div that should be crossed out can vary, so crossing out should be adaptive as well.

Basically I need to make something like this: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0515d31j22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```css
.strike {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.strike:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 120%;
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="strike">$55.55</div>

<br><br>

<div class="strike">$555.55</div>

<br><br>

<div class="strike">$5555.55</div>
```

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning that, the rotate degree needs to be changed based on the length of the content.

Comment: Ive updated my answer with some larger prices. So long as the price doesn't exceed the thousands the strike-through should work as required.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of linear gradients can do this and it will auto-size to the dimensions of the element and no degree notation is required.

```css
div {
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    border:1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, red 51%, transparent 51%, transparent 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, red 51%, transparent 51%, transparent 100%);

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```